# How do I set the request headers using Reqwest?

Tags: http, http-headers, rust, reqwest

I need to make a GET request to a website with a cookie using the Reqwest library. I figured out how to send a GET request:

```
let response = reqwest::get("http://example.com")?;
```

How do I send the same request but adding some custom headers?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

## Reqwest 0.10

Starting at the [crate's documentation](https://docs.rs/reqwest/0.10.1/reqwest/), we see:

> For a single request, you can use the [`get`](https://docs.rs/reqwest/0.10.1/reqwest/fn.get.html) shortcut method.

[`get`'s documentation](https://docs.rs/reqwest/0.10.1/reqwest/fn.get.html) states:

> This function creates a new internal `Client` on each call, and so should not be used if making many requests. Create a [`Client`](https://docs.rs/reqwest/0.10.1/reqwest/struct.Client.html) instead.

[`Client`](https://docs.rs/reqwest/0.10.1/reqwest/struct.Client.html) has a `request` method which states:

> Returns a `RequestBuilder`, which will allow setting headers and request body before sending.

`RequestBuilder` has a [`header` method](https://docs.rs/reqwest/0.10.1/reqwest/struct.RequestBuilder.html#method.header). This can be used as:

```
use reqwest::header::USER_AGENT;

let client = reqwest::Client::new();
let res = client
    .get("https://www.rust-lang.org")
    .header(USER_AGENT, "My Rust Program 1.0")
    .send()
    .await?;
```

---

> How do I add custom headers?

If you look at the signature for [`header`](https://docs.rs/reqwest/0.10.1/reqwest/struct.RequestBuilder.html#method.header), you will see that it accepts generic types:

```
pub fn header<K, V>(self, key: K, value: V) -> RequestBuilder where
    HeaderName: TryFrom<K>,
    <HeaderName as TryFrom<K>>::Error: Into<Error>,
    HeaderValue: TryFrom<V>,
    <HeaderValue as TryFrom<V>>::Error: Into<Error>,
```

There is [an implementation of `TryFrom<&'a str>` for `HeaderName`](https://docs.rs/reqwest/0.10.1/reqwest/header/struct.HeaderName.html#impl-TryFrom%3C%26%27a%20str%3E), so you can use a string literal:

```
use reqwest; // 0.10.0
use tokio; // 0.2.6

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), reqwest::Error> {
    let client = reqwest::Client::new();
    let res = client
        .get("https://www.rust-lang.org")
        .header("X-My-Custom-Header", "foo")
        .send()
        .await?;

    Ok(())
}
```

Comment: Thanks for digging deep. This should really be more explicit in the documentation.

Comment: Can also now add multiple headers with .headers() instead of .header() and   let mut headers = reqwest::header::HeaderMap::new(); headers.insert(reqwest::header::USER_AGENT,reqwest::header::HeaderValue::from_static("curl"));

Answer (score 13):

Send Cookie in reqwest client with version ~0.9.19

```rust
use reqwest; // 0.9.19
use http::{HeaderMap, HeaderValue, header::{COOKIE}};

// create client first
let init_client = reqwest::Client::builder()
        .cookie_store(true).build().unwrap();
// create Header Map
// Here cookie store is optional based on if making more than one request with the // same client 
let mut headers = HeaderMap::new();
headers.insert(COOKIE, HeaderValue::from_str("key=value").unwrap());
let resp = init_client.get("api")
           .headers(headers)
           .query(&[("name", "foo")])
           .send()
           .map(|resp|{
               println!("{:?}", resp.status());
               resp
           })
           .map_err(|err|{
              println!("{:?}", err);
              err
           });
```

Hope This may help.